# What platform is Db2 running on

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw, db2-zos

I was asked to connect to a Db2 database on my company's mainframe. I was given the host name, port number and database. I was able to successfully connect to it using Java with the IBM JDK version 1.8 and the Db2 Universal JDBC driver. Now that I am connected to it, how do I find out what is the under lying mainframe platform. Where it is z/OS, OS/400 or VSE? Are there any SQL queries that can get that platform information? Also how do I find out what is the version of the Db2?

Comment: OS/400 doesn't run on mainframes.

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238668/db2-cross-platform-function-variable/238736#238736) might be of use.

Comment: @mustaccio : Yes, that answer was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Querying `SYSPROC.ENV_GET_INST_INFO` will give level info on LUW, for Z/OS `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`, I'm not sure about OS/400... Also [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) should give you vendor-agnostic info about the database you are connected to